# No SQL extension on apache running php 7.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I `a2enmod php7.4` and `a2dismod php7.3` on apache & Ubuntu and my Wordpress sites stopped working saying cannot connect to database.

Upon further investigation through phpinfo mysqli is not enabled with php7.4. If I reenable php7.3 then mysqli is enabled, switch back to 7.4 and nothing.

I have tried looking at php.ini and adding:

`extension=php_mysqli`

`extension=php_mysqli.so`

No change.

I have tried running `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`  and it says it is already installed.

I have tried running `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql`  and it says that doesn't exist.

Does php7.4 not support mysqli at all?

Comment: Try `phpenmod mysqli` first. As Ubuntu is Debian based, it may be the same in php.ini : `extension=mysqli.so`

Comment: @ThierryLeroux It says WARNING: Module mysqli ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available

Answer (score 2):

OK I've found it.

Need to add repository: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Then `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql`